# Excel 2013 - PC - conditional formatting with multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have a project that covers 2 sheets. It concerns doing inventory for small businesses.

On sheet 1 there is a schedule of inventories and purchases that a business can make each month. On sheet 2 there are the summations of the various months' inventories so as to see how much the business should have in sales. Every cell in sheet 2 (60 rows, 600 columns) contains a calculation from data in sheet 1.

I am trying to make it so that the numbers in sheet 2 will appear the same as the background color (and therefore invisible) unless a value has been entered into each of the necessary cells in sheet 1. In order to do this, each cell is given 2 conditional formats.

For example:
Sheet2(B2): =Sheet1!$D$3=""
and
Sheet2(B2): =Sheet1!$B$3=""

The result works perfectly when I enter these individual formats for each cell. The problem is that there are 36,000 cells and I cannot figure out how to copy the formats across multiple cells. 
Each cell on sheet 2 is the result of a different set of values from sheet 1.

Does anybody have any advice on how to copy these formats across multiple columns, rows, etc?

Answer (score 0):

So your question how to copy the format on multiple cells at once. Just copy the cell then select the others cells and choose paste as format from paste special.

Comment: I've tried pasting like you said but the problem is that the new cells are always being changed based on the input values for the original cell.

I want to make it so that the conditional format of each individual cell is decided by a different set of values from Sheet 1.

For example, Sheet2!(J3) is set to be a certain color if:
=Sheet1!$R$3=""
and 
=Sheet1!$S$3=""

However, Sheet2!K3 is set to be the same color, but this time if:
=Sheet1!$T$3=""
and
=Sheet1$V$3=""

How do I copy that format so that each cell receives inputs from different values on Sheet 1?